# Laravel 5 - Change model file location

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I moved over to Laravel 5 from Laravel 4. One major change I'm seeing is that all model files must be placed under the `/app` directory.

How do I configure my laravel 5 installation so that I can place my model files under `/app/Models` and also use the models in the usual `FooModel::with(...)` (for example) way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the folder to the `composer.json` classmap:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I`m using laravel 5.8 but it doesnt work. I'm trying to make it work with artisan generators. e.g. php artisan make:controller FooController -p Bar --api . This will try to find the parent Bar in App/Bar and not App/Models/Bar

Comment: Perfect. It worked properly 
After changing classmap in composer.json.
this command is needed to run.
composer dump-autoload.

Best

Answer (score 18):

you just need to namespace the models accordingly.

```
namespace App\Models\User
```

and wherever you may need to use them just reference them with the correct namespace.

```
use App\Models\User
```

Comment: i assume there may be cases where a `php artisan optimize` could be required too. since an update will trigger both automatically, i would just go with update. it's not really that expensive.

Comment: Good point. I still prefer to run the actual command I want to run. If I want to update I run `composer update` if I want to regenerate the autoloading files I run `composer dump-autoload` and so on... Also I usually make don't use optimize when in development so I don't have to worry about re-pre-compiling things ;)

Comment: with Laravel 5.3 config/auth.php also need a change in path for User table

Comment: You do not need to use `composer dump-autoload`. Laravel is using PSR-4 autolader for the `app/` folder. Only folder that is using `classmap` is `database` where you would need to run it.

Comment: whats missing here is that artisan make:model still creates the model in the app directory.

Comment: @woens just do `php artisan make:model Models\\NewModel`

Comment: @conrad, you're right. But its all together a bit cumbersome. Taylor went into great lengths to put everything in its own directory but somehow moved the models to an awkward default
location. I can't get the reasoning behind this. Even laravel 3 already had the models in a separate directory.

Answer (score 10):

Only **Two** places to change ...

1) At **namespace** in User.php

```
namespace App\Models;
```

When Use it,

```
use App\Models\User;
```

2) In `config/auth.php`

```
'providers' => [
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\User::class,
],
```

Note: After changing 2) ... Don't forget to `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear` at command line.

Comment: This must be the right answer as it indicates to change the config also .Thanks this works very well